# How to configure WebDAV in Tridion 2011 sp1

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

We are using Tridion 2011 SP1.  We are using NTLM Authentication. We are tying to map network drive for WebDAV, when we enter CMS url/webdav and press next it is throwing error "The folder your entered does not appear to be valid.  Please choose another".  We checked in IIS under SDL Tridion 2011 website webdav folder is there.  I think we are missing on some configuration can anyone help us to figure out this.

Comment: btw, consider asking Tridion questions on http://tridion.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

Common error. I guess you're doing this on the server itself? There's some additional stuff you must add to Windows for it to support Webdav folders ("Desktop Experience Feature" I believe).

Try it from an actual client machine instead of the server itself, there's usually nothing that needs to be changed on the Tridion side for this to work.

**If you are using Windows XP**, please note that the default webdav client is broken and it will try to convert your url from `http://servername/webdav/` to `\\servername\webdav`. If this is the case, open it first from an MS Office application (it will use the office webdav client which works better than XP's) and then open the shortcut from your "My Network" list in explorer.

Connecting from Windows 7 to Tridion webdav has always worked for me.

Comment: I tried to do it from client machine which is running Windows XP Professional.  Now it is asking user id and pwd again and again.

Comment: are you using the format DOMAIN\USERNAME? If it is a local user, the domain can be '.'

Comment: "We are using NTLM Authentication" - what does this mean? Users in a Domain? Locally defined on the server?

Comment: We can't find registry path HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM
\CurrentControlSet\Services\WebClient\Parameters given in installation manual step 3.8.2, are we missing any configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Inorder to find the path you have to install the DesktopExperience feature as Nuno Linhares proposed